# PHP mode for GNU emacs not listed as a MELPA package

Tags: php, emacs, melpa, php-mode, emacs26

I want to install [PHP mode for GNU emacs](http://melpa.org/#/php-mode).

The documentation says:

> With GNU Emacs 24 or later then you can use its package feature to
>   install PHP Mode from MELPA.

But when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `list-packages` I do not see this mode listed.

Why?

Comment: Have you configured the MELPA package archive?

Comment: Yes, I did in `.emacs` files

Comment: I can't replicate the issue -- I can see `php-mode` in the list.  I presume that you can see (lots of) other packages in the list with "melpa" indicated in the 'archive' column?

Comment: In either case, see whether`M-x package-refresh-contents` sorts it out.

Comment: When I open emacs and list the packages, it shows the list is updating by itself but php-mode never appeared ....  when I typed the command you suggested, I finally see it. If you want to transform your comment into an answer, I will be glad to upvote and accept it. Thank you very much @phils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that your local listing of packages is synchronised with the upstream package archives, use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-refresh-contents`, and then <kbd>M-x</kbd> `list-packages` again.